# How to use nested loops to output powers of integers and their expanded form, respectively

Tags: java, loops

I want to output the power table from n (0) to n (10) with just the base being inputted using the scanner.

For now, I am having difficulties in setting it up

Code:

```
else if (option == 2){
                int base = keyboard.nextInt();
                for (int x = base; x <= base; x++){
                    System.out.print(base+"^");
                    for (int y = 0; y <= 10; y++){ // "y" is exponent
                        System.out.print(y+"=");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

Sample input:

```
  2
  5
```

Expected Output:

```
     5^0=
     5^1=
     5^2=
     5^3=
     - - - several lines are skipped here - - -
     5^10=
```

Note: This is not the expected output, but I want to try out the code by myself this is just the step that would take me to the end result

Comment: HussainOmer123 - I just answered a similar question as your edited question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050129/how-do-i-make-my-answer-print-correctly-in-java/62050547#62050547).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

1. You have used `result` inside the loop and therefore it is getting reset with each iteration.
2. You have put the print statement inside the loop
3. You need to multiply `result` with `base` with each iteration which is not done.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = keyboard.nextInt();
        int base = keyboard.nextInt();
        int exponent = keyboard.nextInt();
        int result = 1;
        if (option == 1) {
            for (int x = base; x <= base; x++) {
                if (exponent <= 1) {
                    System.out.print(base + "^" + exponent);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(base + "^" + exponent + "=");
                }
                for (int y = 1; y <= exponent; y++) {
                    System.out.print(exponent == 1 ? "" : (base + (y < exponent ? "*" : "")));
                    result *= base;
                }
                System.out.print("=" + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
1
2
5
2^5=2*2*2*2*2=32
```

**[Update]**

As per your comment, you haven't learnt [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) but I strongly recommend you learn it. The solution given below is without using the ternary operator:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = keyboard.nextInt();
        int base = keyboard.nextInt();
        int exponent = keyboard.nextInt();
        int result = 1;
        if (option == 1) {
            for (int x = base; x <= base; x++) {
                if (exponent <= 1) {
                    System.out.print(base + "^" + exponent);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(base + "^" + exponent + "=");
                }
                for (int y = 1; y <= exponent; y++) {
                    if (y < exponent) {
                        System.out.print(base + "*");
                    } else if (exponent != 1) {
                        System.out.print(base);
                    }
                    result *= base;
                }
                System.out.print("=" + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214638/discussion-on-answer-by-arvind-kumar-avinash-how-to-use-nested-loops-to-output-p).

Comment: Hello Arvind, could you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144653/how-to-change-colors-of-a-circle-using-a-timer-in-a-java-gui

Comment: @HussainOmer - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143096/im-trying-to-print-out-prime-number-but-not-sure-whats-wrong-with-my-code/64143167#comment113431358_64143167).

Comment: Hello Arvind, could you answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266140/how-to-make-the-program-to-check-the-instance-of-a-letter-in-java Its not GUI but more with arrays