# How do i make my answer print correctly in java

Tags: java, math, exponent

I am having an issue where when my program prints `(base)^0=`, it doesn't print the answer (1)
(I shorend down the out put examples as I'm only having an issue with the first line of the output)

> expected output:
>
> ```
> 2^0=1
> 2^1=2
> 2^2=2*2=4
> 2^3=2*2*2=8
> 2^4=2*2*2*2=16
> ```

actual output:

```
> 2^0=
> 2^1=2=2
> 2^2=2*2=4
> 2^3=2*2*2=8
> 2^4=2*2*2*2=16
```

code:

```
else if(option == 2){
        base = Input.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i+=1){
            System.out.print(base+"^"+i+"=");
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j+=1){
                 if(j != i -1){
                System.out.print(base+"*");
                }else{
                    
                        System.out.format(base+"="+"%.0f",Math.pow(base,i));
                    
                }
                
            }
        
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: dont mind the other output issues, i can fix those, I just don't know why it is not out putting 1 on in the first line

Comment: hi @andreas, your for loop `for(int j = 0; j < i; j+=1){` is never executed for i=0 as you are checking if j=0 is less than i=0, and hence it is printing empty string in the last sys out

Answer (score 1):

The first round when `i = 0`, you don't enter the inner for loop as the condition to enter is `j < i`, that is `0 < 0` => `false`

Comment: ohh ok, how would i fix that

Comment: A super dirty way could be a simple `if (i == 0) print("1")` at the right place, that is next to the inner for, doesn't matter if before or after :)