# How to make the program to check the instance of a letter in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a cash register where I have to use a scanner and can only have 5 input amounts. It has to also include hst and that is by only having a "h" after or before an amount. My question is how would the program recognize that I have put an "h" after or before an amount? This seems to be done only using a string variable, so how would I accomplish that? I have to store the inputs in an array, and so I got that to work.

My Code:

```
 // Import scanner class
 import java.util.Scanner;

// Create class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Declare the scanner object and create scanner variables
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press any key to start");
String key = inp.nextLine();
System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

// Define an array double variable, set the limit to 5 inputs
double[] numbers = new double[5];

// Create a for loop to input any numbers 5 times
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){

    // Add a scanner input to let the user type out the values
    numbers[i] = inp.nextDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "This seems to be done only using a string variable, so how would I accomplish that?"  Then get a String via [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) so you can check the first/last char for 'h'.  After extracting the number part, use `parseDouble` to convert it to a numeric data type.  Have you been taught String manipulation methods yet?

Comment: Yes I have been

Comment: Alright, so after using code like Hades posted below, you'll need [String.substring()](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/) to get just the number part so that you can pass that to `parseDouble()`.

Comment: May I ask what is 'hst'?

Comment: @User234 have posted an updated answer let me know if thats what u r looking for

Comment: @Hades Not really because I am not supposed to use arrayIndex or arrayasList

Comment: "arrayIndex" is just a variable...exactly like the "i" in your original post.  The "arrayasList" is just being used to show you the contents of the array.  You wouldn't use that in your final program...

Comment: @User234 , Idle_Mind is correct those are variable name and just to show the result, just to make things clearer and easy i have renamed arrayIndex to index also instead of arraylist i used a for loop to print valid values

Answer (score 1):

below code asks the user input for 5 times , and only valid values will be in the Array , Vald values are the values with 'h' at start or end and should only occur once. i.e. at 'h' at both end and start or more than once is invalid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int counter = 1;
    Double[] result = new Double[5];
    
    int index = 0;
    while(counter <= 5) {           
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an Amount ");
        String value = scanner.nextLine();      
        int indexOfH = value.indexOf("h");
        int lastIndexOfH = value.lastIndexOf("h");
        boolean containsHatstartsOrEnd = indexOfH == 0 || indexOfH == (value.length()-1);
    
        if(containsHatstartsOrEnd && indexOfH==lastIndexOfH){ //Validate h at begins or end and should contains only once
            result[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
            index++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Printing Valid values");

    for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++) {
        if(result[i]!=null) {
            System.out.println(result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**input & result**

```
Enter an Amount 13.45h
Enter an Amount 55h.65
Enter an Amount 32h.33h
Enter an Amount h100.23
Enter an Amount h20
Printing Valid values
13.45
100.23
20.0
```

Comment: I need to store the inputs in an array

Comment: @User234 Then do that. Wrap the code below the scanner instantiation in a loop to get multiple values and then put the extracted values in an array.

Comment: Note the subtle difference in your array declarations.  The original used lowercase `double` to make an array of PRIMITIVE doubles.  The code by Hades is using uppercase `Double` to have an array of double wrappers.  In the example at the bottom, the 2nd and 3rd inputs are invalid (no "h" at the beginning or end), so no value was put into the array at those positions.  For those indices, a `null` will be present in the array since `Double` is a REFERENCE type.  This difference is difficult to understand for most beginners...

Comment: @Idle_Mind yess !! You have an eagle eye and thanks for the explanation +1 for the osam explanation :)